# How to cancel “Hide user from channel” on Youtube comment?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I accidentally clicked "Hide user from channel" on a Youtube comment of one of my videos. This seems to have the consequence of shadowhiding it (i.e. the user who posted the comment still sees it, but not the other users)

How can I cancel it? I don't find the option in Youtube to revert this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your hidden users in the [YouTube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com) > Settings > Community

Comment: yes but the comments don't come back even when the hidden user is unselected

Comment: Yep, same here. Did that accidentally. Now I removed the user from the black list and the comments are gone. Looks like, this shadow banning actually does the same as deleting a comment on a public feed. But it keeps the local copy for the user who initially wrote it. Has anyone found a way around it?

Comment: The link goes to some random YouTube channel?!

Comment: updated the answer to reflect the current UI @ChristianRauchenwald